# SOLR join query in distributed configuration

Tags: join, solr, solrcloud

I'm running SOLR4 and run some join queries, for example - `{!join from=some_id to=another_id}(a_id:55 AND some_type_id:3)`

When I run single instance of SOLR4 (not cloud) this query returns 4 results, exactly how it is supposed to be.

But when I run it on SOLR cloud, with two shards and two replicas it returns only one result, while another 3 could be found in the index if searched directly by id, for example.

Any ideas what is wrong and/or how to fix it?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Join works only within the shard. Join will not work across the shards. I think one shard should having 3 documents matching the condition and another shard should have one. Complex joins across shards yet to come.

If you want join as mandatory feature, think about single shard with multiple replication as work around.

Comment: I have a similar usecase where I want to use join query on solrcloud5 but join across shard isn't supported. however if create only one shard and multiple replication then ingestion speed goes down drastically and query response time is very high. is there any strategy to tweak document sharding strategy?

Answer (score 0):

When creating shards in Solr you can set the router to `compositeId` and when indexing documents you can insert ID prefixes into the ID attribute which will help Solr to select a shard for documents. In other words, all documents with the same ID prefix will be stored on a single shard. While you can't use this to tell Solr which shard exactly to use, you can indicate docs that need to be stored on a single shard.

For example, if you index Posts and Comments then your ID attribute for a Post could look like `POSTDATA123!Post 123`, where `123` is the Post ID. When indexing a Comment that belongs to a Post with the ID `123` the ID attribute could be `POSTDATA123!Comment 321`, where `321` is the Comment ID. Solr will understand this prefix `POSTDATA123!` on both documents and will store both Post and its Comments on a single shard.

When indexing multiple Posts Solr will still use shards and spread your posts across available shards evenly but joins will work because Comments will be always stored on the same shard as their parent Post.

You can find more docs about the `compositeId` router here https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/shards-and-indexing-data-in-solrcloud.html